# Vue js axios request to Spring Boot API Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, nginx, spring-security

My Vue js (Nuxt) frontend makes axios requests to a backend Spring Boot API. Everything works fine. Now I tried to enable Basic Auth with Spring Boot security (LDAP).

When I directly access my API a simple browser login popup appears. It works. The problem is when my frontend makes API axios requests, I get HTTP 401.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401

Spring Boot does not register anything...

My Spring Boot SecurityConfig

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    }
```

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource().url(ldapUrl)
            .and()
            .userSearchFilter(userSearchFilter);
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Do I need to configure my frontend additionally?
Furthermore my frontend uses NGINX

Comment: Can you provide any Logs of your frontend and backend application please?

If i'd just have to guess i'd say that your OPTIONS call is blocked because you didn't explicity allow it in your Cors Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can only guess and you're not receiving any further information.

Try to add `configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);` to the CorsConfiguration.

Like:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

This will (or can) work because of the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Furthermore, did you check if it works without authentication?